# Multi stage CIC simulation using python control.matlab

Tags: python, matlab, scilab

I want to obtain frequency response of a multi-stage CIC filter.

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from control.matlab import *
    
def main():
    mm=256
    nn=5
    dt=True

    omega_range=np.linspace(0.00,np.pi,100000)

    syscic=tf([1,],[1,],dt)
    num=np.zeros(mm+1);num[0]=1;num[-1]=-1
    den=np.zeros(mm+1);den[0]=1;den[1]=-1
    # print(den)
    for n in range(nn):
        syscic=syscic*tf(num,den,dt)/mm

    bode(syscic, omega_range,dB=True, deg=True)
    plt.show()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Unexpected response is seen in the very low frequencies.
(It should be 0dB at DC)
If nn is less than 3, I get right results.

[The result, nn=5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNX5r.png)

I guess this is numerical errors due to that num and den come close to zero.

On the other hand, Scilab calculates correctly, even with 10 stages.

Is there any solution using the python control library?

My environment is:
Windows 10, Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit),
control (0.7.0) installed by pip, and no slycot.

Comment: Your `for` statement seems to be always the same, since you don't use the value of `n`. Is it the expected behavior ?

Comment: @PTRK
    syscic=syscic*tf(num,den,dt)/mm
is executed nn times (this case 5 times), while n is not used.
I think the code works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following code:

```
#!python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from control.matlab import *
import control

def main():
    mm=256
    nn=5
    dt=True

    omega_range=np.linspace(0.00,np.pi,100000)

    #syscic=tf([1.,],[1.,],dt)
    num=np.zeros(mm+1);num[0]=1;num[-1]=-1
    den=np.zeros(mm+1);den[0]=1;den[1]=-1
    tf1=control.tf(num,den,dt)/mm
    ss1=control.tf2ss(tf1) 
    syscic=reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,nn*[ss1,]) 
    bode(syscic, omega_range,dB=True, deg=True)
    plt.show()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the result I got:

[image: result]